# gitlab - Docker command not found when executing a shell script

Tags: docker, gitlab

I am executing a pipeline with all dependencies and integration tests. For integration tests I have written one shell script which runs docker image for postgres db and put execute the queries within it. In my .`gitlab-ci.yml` file when I put the stage of integration test and run the pipeline then when it executes the shell script then it says docker not found.
Whereas if I run `docker info` in any of the stage in `.gitlab-ci.yml` then it is executed properly…

The script has command -

```
docker run --rm --name pg_test -d -p 5100:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=pg -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=aaaaaa -e POSTGRES_DB=db_test postgres:9.6
```

> Error - Successfully started process ‘command ‘sh’’
>   ./src/integration/scripts/testDBSetup.sh: line 1: docker: not found

The expectation is that the script should be executed properly and the docker should be available within it.

We are using self-managed git-lab and shared resources.

**gitlab stages**

```
image: deskera/docker-with-aws

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

services:
  - docker:19.03.0-dind

stages:
  - docker-test
  - integration-test

before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle

cache:
  key: gradle-cache-test
  paths:
     - .gradle/wrapper/
     - .gradle/caches/

docker-test:
  stage: docker-test
  script: docker info             #working

integration-test:
  image: gradle:alpine
  stage: integration-test
  script:
    - gradle itest --info          #not working
```

**build.gradle code**:

```
task setupTestDB(type :Exec){
    commandLine 'sh','./src/integration/scripts/testDBSetup.sh'
}

task itest(type: Test, dependsOn: "test") {
    description = 'Runs the integration tests.'
    dependsOn setupTestDB
    useTestNG()
    mustRunAfter test
}
```

**testDBSetup.sh** :

```
docker run --rm --name pg_test -d -p 5100:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=pg -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=aaaaaa -e POSTGRES_DB=db_test postgres:9.6
```

Comment: if you try add `image: gradle:alpine` in the `docker-test`job, is the `docker info` still working ?

Comment: @NicolasPepinster - You are correct, the `docker-info` doesn't work if I add `image: gradle:alpine` in the stage `docker-test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitLab CI offers a feature called [services](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#what-is-a-service) which let's you run additional containers that are automatically linked to your job. It seems that this is exactly what you want to achieve. There is also an [example for Postgres](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/postgres.html).

For your job `docker-test` you don't define an image. Therefore, it runs in `deskera/docker-with-aws` which obviously contains a Docker installation. Your integration test runs in a Alpine Linux container which usually doesn't contain a Docker installation.

Solution 1:
You create an image containing `docker` and `gradle` as described by Nicolas Pepinster.

Solution 2:
You add a parameter to your integration test to distinguish between local development environment and GitLab CI. Then use a service to run your Postgres database.

Comment: I am already using services services: - `docker:19.03.0-dind` and I need to execute docker image for postgres only so that the same script can be used locally and also via gitlab Please refer updated post with actual .gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: I see. But then you probably have to build a custom image to run your integration test. An image that contains Docker and Gradle. Is it not possible to have a parameterized test script and use a service in GitLab CI and the manually started container locally?

Comment: Yes the service is in my .gitlab-ci.yml file as shown in the post. I tried couple of images but none of them worked - shifudao/docker-gradle, dtforce/dind-gradle, keeganwitt/docker-gradle-root. Should I create new custom image? Or anyone existing can work?

Comment: It's up to you. In my humble opinion it's not worth the effort. I'm not really familiar with Gradle, but adding just a parameter as described before sounds much easier.

Answer (score 1):

As @lukket said, `gradle:alpine` image doesn't contain docker runtime.

You need to create a image containing `docker` and `gradle`. You can use dind java image like [this one](https://github.com/legacyshield/dind-java) because gradle need java.

Once your image is build, in your `integration-test` job, refer your nuew built image :

```
integration-test:
  image: dind-gradle:latest
  stage: integration-test
  script:
    - gradle itest --info
```

Keep also the service `docker:19.03.0-dind` in your config file.

Comment: Yes the service is in my .gitlab-ci.yml file as shown in the post. I tried couple of images but none of them worked - `shifudao/docker-gradle`, `dtforce/dind-gradle`, `keeganwitt/docker-gradle-root`. Should I create new custom image? Or anyone existing can work?

Comment: I thought `dtforce/dind-gradle`could work as docker is installed explicitly in the `Dockerfile` but I tested and it's not the case. I'm afraid that you need to create your own image.